# How would I go about stopping a decrement at 0 while using React useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently making a simple card-battle style game using React and making use of the useState hook to dynamically render the HP of the characters chosen. But when the user attacks the opponent, instead of the Opponent's HP stopping at 0 it goes negative until the user clicks attack and then it will log that the user has won. It's the same when the Opponent defeats the User. I've attached my code, but how would I go about making the HP stop at 0 instead of going negative?

```
    const newOpp = {...oppChar};
    const newMain = {...mainChar};

    const [oppAlive, setOppAlive] = useState(true);
    const [userAlive, setUserAlive] = useState(true);
    const [oppHealth, setOppHealth] = useState(newOpp.hp);
    const [userHealth, setUserHealth] = useState(newMain.hp);
    const [specialEligible, setSpecialEligible] = useState(false);
    
    const attackOpponent = () => { 
        if (oppHealth > 0) {
            setOppHealth(oppHealth - newMain.attack + newOpp.defense)
        } else if (oppHealth === 0) {
            return;
        } if (oppHealth < 0) {
            alert(`You have defeated ${newOpp.name} the ${newOpp.type}`)
            setOppAlive(!oppAlive)
        }
    }

    <div className="flex flex-col items-center bg-white border-2 border-blue-400 my-4">
        <img src={mainChar.avatar} alt={mainChar.name} className="h-quarter my-2"/>
        <h2>{mainChar.name} the {mainChar.type}</h2>
        <p>Attack: <span className="text-blue-600"><strong>{mainChar.attack}</strong></span></p>
        <p>Defence: <span className="text-blue-600"><strong>{mainChar.defense}</strong></span></p>
        <p>HP: <span className="text-blue-600 text-2xl"><strong>{userHealth}</strong></span></p>
        <button className="p-2 m-3 bg-plum-web rounded-md text-xl font-cardo hover:text-royal-gold hover:bg-dark-purple" id="btn" onClick={attackOpponent}>Attack</button>
        {specialEligible ? 
             <button className="p-2 m-3 bg-royal-gold rounded-md text-xl font-cardo hover:text-royal-gold hover:bg-dark-purple" onClick={specialAttack}>Special Attack</button> : null    
        }
    </div>
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center bg-white border-2 border-blue-400 my-4">
        <img src={oppChar.avatar} alt={oppChar.name} className="h-quarter my-2" />
        <h2>{oppChar.name} the {oppChar.type}</h2>
        <p>Attack: <span className="text-blue-600"><strong>{oppChar.attack}</strong></span></p>
        <p>Defence: <span className="text-blue-600"><strong>{oppChar.defense}</strong></span></p>
        <p>HP: <span className="text-blue-600 text-2xl"><strong>{oppHealth}</strong></span></p>
    </div>
```

I'm a beginner in React and know I'll probably have to go through and refactor and fix some things in my code that might not be best practice/most efficient but would appreciate any help/feedback please :)

Comment: this seems wrong `setOppAlive(!oppAlive)` why to toggle the oppAlive? shouldn't be false?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a useEffect hook to determine when a user's hp goes lower than 0. Something like this would fix the issue for you.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (oppHealth < 0) {

    // Fix health with a negative value;
    setOppHealth(0);
    setOppAlive(false);

  } else if (userHealth<0) {

    setUserHealth(0);
    setUserAlive(false);

  }
}, [oppHealth, userHealth]);
```

Comment: No he shouldn't. This is very dangerous because you can endup with an infinitive loop if he try expand the effect

Answer (score 0):

After your character receive a big hit, the math will make its hp negative .

To fix this, just limit the minimum value of hp:

```js
// instead of
setOppHealth(oppHealth - newMain.attack + newOpp.defense)

// do it
const nextOppHealth = oppHealth - newMain.attack + newOpp.defense
setOppHealth(nextOppHealth < 0 ? 0 : nextOppHealth)

// or
setOppHealth(Math.max(oppHealth - newMain.attack + newOpp.defense, 0))
```

The other way, keep the hp negative but showing it as 0:

```js
<p>HP: <span className="text-blue-600 text-2xl"><strong>{Math.max(oppHealth, 0)}</strong></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with early return on attack when life is less then zero.
Also you can use `useMemo` to check if oppIsAlive.

```js
const [oppHealth, setOppHealth] =  useState(100);
const oppIsAlive = useMemo(() => oppHealth > 0, [oppHealth]);

const attack = useCallback(() => {
  if(!oppIsAlive) return;
  setOppHealth(/*your calculation*/);
}, [oppIsAlive])
```